# Problema con el diseñador

Tags: android-studio

Ya instale Android Studio y descargue las API's y todo pero al usar el diseñador este no me funciona debido a que si muestra el diseñador pero si arrastro alguna herramienta o algo asi no muestra nada mas que un punto en el lugar donde lo arrastre. Por si acaso soy usuario de Arch Linux

[image: En la imagen se ve que ya he agregado un TextView además de un button pero no se ve en el diseñador]

En la imagen se ve que ya he agregado un TextView además de un button pero no se ve en el diseñador

[image: Esto es lo unico que se muestra en diseñador]

Esto es lo unico que se muestra en diseñador

Comment: muestra una imagen de tu problema, soy usuario de Arch y no he tenido esos problemas.

Comment: ahi dejo algunas imagenes

Comment: Esta semana se han hecho varias preguntas similares que obtuvieron respuesta. ¿Has probado si alguna de ellas te funciona?

Comment: Como te ha dicho Alvaro últimamente se formulan muchas preguntas por errores como el tuyo, puede ser por varias razones, pero busca las preguntas parecidas a la tuya, seguro que alguna de las respuestas dadas te sirve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estuvo buscando un poco y ya consegui solventar el problema lo unico que tenia que hacer es, en el archivo res/values/styles.xml cambiar esto:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

por esto:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

con eso ya quedaba solventado el asunto del diseñador